# Proving a function to be an open map

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, continuity, open-map

How can we prove that the function $f: S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ defined as $z \mapsto z^2$ is a continuous and open map using topological arguments? Here $S^1$ represents the unit circle in complex plane, centred at the origin.

I could prove that it is a continuous map since the map $F: \Bbb C \rightarrow \Bbb C$ defined as  $z \mapsto z^2$ is a continuous map because it is a polynomial function. Moreover, $f$ is just the restriction of $F$ on $S^1$ i.e. $f = F|_{S^1}$ and because restrictions of continuous maps are continuous (via the subspace topology), $f$ is also continuous.

But I could not solve that $f$ is an open map so please help me with that.
Also, please verify whether my proof is correct.

Comment: I think open mapping theorem will do the job. ( It's just my thought...Am I right? )

Comment: Can you use that $f\colon\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ is a local homeomorphism? This follows from, say, the inverse function theorem, but you can also get it at a cheaper price.

Comment: @Believer I want to use topological properties to prove. Nevertheless, I don't think your proof will work because f is not distributive over intersections until and unless it is injective which it is not. We have to consider this property since because any open set in $S^1$ is intersection of open set in $\Bbb C$ and $S^1$.

Comment: Oh !! so silly of me to not check linearity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A$ be an open subset of $S^1$. If $A=\emptyset$, then $f(A)=\emptyset$, which is an open set. Otherwise, take $z\in A$ and let $\theta\in\Bbb R$ be such that $e^{i\theta}=z$. Since $A$ is open, there is a $\alpha\in\left(0,\frac\pi2\right)$ such that$$\varphi\in(\theta-\alpha,\theta+\alpha)\implies e^{i\varphi}\in A.$$But then $f(e^{i\varphi})=(e^{i\varphi})^2=e^{2i\varphi}$ and so$$f(A)\supset\{e^{i\varphi}\mid\varphi\in(2\theta-2\alpha,2\theta+2\alpha)\}.$$So, $f(A)$ is an open set.

Comment: How did you conclude that $f(A)\supset\{e^{i\alpha}\mid\alpha\in(2\theta-2\alpha,2\theta+2\alpha)\}$?

Comment: I meant to write$$f(A)\supset\{e^{i\varphi}\mid\varphi\in(2\theta-2\alpha,2\theta+2\alpha)\}.$$Is it clear why? If not, I can explain. But it just because $f(e^{i\varphi})=e^{2i\varphi}$.

Comment: No, it is still not clear. Please explain

Comment: If $A$ contains the numbers of the form $e^{i\varphi}$, with $\varphi\in(\theta-\alpha,\theta+\alpha$, then $f(A)$ contains the images of those numbers and, since $\left(e^{i\varphi}\right)^2=e^{2i\varphi}$, these images are the numbers of the form $e^{i\varphi}$ with $\varphi\in(2\theta-2\alpha,2\theta+2\alpha)$.

Comment: okay,,,i got it. But just as a side question, shouldn't then $f(A)=\{e^{i\varphi}\mid\varphi\in(2\theta-2\alpha,2\theta+2\alpha)\}$ ? although superset will also work, just wanted to make sure for brevity

Comment: No. I am only assuming that $A$ *contains* the set $\{e^{i\varphi}\mid\varphi\in(\theta-\alpha,\theta+\alpha)\}$, not that it is equal to it.

Comment: I am sorry for my previous comment but if $f(A)\supset\{e^{i\varphi}\mid\varphi\in(2\theta-2\alpha,2\theta+2\alpha)\}.$ holds, then we can only conclude that $f(A)$ is a neighbourhood of $f(z)$ but not necessarily open. for example, $\{e^{i\varphi}\mid\varphi\in[2\theta-2\alpha,2\theta+2\alpha]\}$ is closed.

Comment: What I proved was that, for each $\omega\in f(A)$, $f(A)$ is a neigborhood of $\omega$. Therefore, $f(A)$ is an open subset of $S^1$.

Comment: okay...so i think you should have written $z \in A$ and not $z \in S^1$. anyways, thanks for your patience.

Comment: You are right. I've edited my answer. If it was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof of continuity is correct.

The fact that the map is open is an immediate consequence of the following fact from Complex Analysis: Every point on $S^{1}$ has  neighborhood on which there is an analytic (hence continuous) branch of square root. The continuity of this square root shows that the $z \to z^{2}$ is (locally, hence globally) open.